# ssh add bad passphrase

Tags: ssh

i have add public form another computer.

on my computer i see the files in the ssh folder

```
user@user-170:~/.ssh$ ls
authorized_keys  config  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts  known_hosts.old
```

now i see the list of keys

```
user@user-170:~/.ssh$ ssh-add -l
2048 fc:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:13 user@user-php (RSA)
```

now i want to add `authorized_keys` which i have added from different computer, but it ask me to enter passphrase and what ever i enter it will just keep asking me about the pass phrase

```
user@user-170:~/.ssh$ ssh-add authorized_keys
Enter passphrase for authorized_keys: 
Bad passphrase, try again for authorized_keys: 
Bad passphrase, try again for authorized_keys: 
Bad passphrase, try again for authorized_keys: 
Bad passphrase, try again for authorized_keys:
```

and it keeps on asking

what passphrase should i give to take it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh-add` is a command for ssh agent, not to add keys.

See http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh

> ssh-add adds RSA or DSA identities to the authentication agent,

See http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add

You might want `ssh-copy-id` or simply cat

```
cat key >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

The password you would enter would be the user password (ssh-copy-id) or the password on the key (ssh-add)